# NoReverseMatch at / (reverse logout)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I get this error on the homepage of my website:

> NoReverseMatch at /
>
> Reverse for 'logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [].

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from profiles import views as profiles_views
from contact import views as contact_views
from checkout import views as checkout_views

urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
 url(r'^$', profiles_views.home, name='home'),
 url(r'^about/$', profiles_views.about, name='about'),
 url(r'^profile/$', profiles_views.userProfile, name='profile'),
 url(r'^checkout/$', checkout_views.checkout, name='checkout'),
 url(r'^contact/$', contact_views.contact, name='contact'),
 url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root= settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render

#Create your views here
def home(request):
    context = {}
    template = 'home.html'
    return render(request,template,context)

def about(request):
    context = {}
    template = 'about.html'
    return render(request,template,context)

@login_required
def userProfile(request):
     user = request.user
     context = {'user': user}
     template = 'profile.html'
     return render(request,template,context)
```

the traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers   \exception.py" in inner
     39.             response = get_response(request)

    File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers  \base.py" in _get_response
     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

      File "C:\Users\Adila\Documents\tryFOUR\src\profiles\views.py" in home
  8.    return render(request,template,context)

    File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
      30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

     File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string



68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  210.                 return template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  210.                 return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  447.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "C:\Users\Adila\Envs\tryFOUR\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  389.             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'logout' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I have looked at other posts and haven't found anything that helped, and I just joined this project so I don't exactly know what the original programmer was trying to do here.

Comment: You may need to put your url for `home` view at the last of urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somewhere in your `home.html` you use

```
{% url 'logout' %}
```

but the 'logout' is absent in your urls

i think you want get logout from `allauth.urls`

```
{% url 'account_logout' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in your 'home.html' or wherever you have used `logout` url, change it into,

```
{% url 'account_logout' %}
```